# How to import .py file into different .py file if they are in different folders?

Tags: python, file, import

I have 2 different .py files, alpha.py and beta.py, located in different folders within the 'letters' project folder. alpha.py is located in the letters/try/test_unit folder and beta.py is located in the letters/src folder.

I want to import the beta.py file in the alpha.py file. In the alpha.py file, I am doing:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/letters/src')
import beta
```

But I keep getting the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beta'. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the beginning of `alpha.py`:

```py
import sys, os
from os.path import dirname
curdir = os.path.realpath(__file__)
parent = dirname(dirname(dirname(curdir)))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(parent, 'src'))

import beta
```

The third line returns the real pathname of the file it's in, which would be `/path/to/.../letters/try/test_unit/alpha.py`. The fourth line will get the parent directory of the parent directory of the parent directory of the file, which would be `/path/to/.../letters`. The fifth line finally adds `letters/src` as a valid directory to find all modules in `src`.

From there, you can now `import beta`.